# yt-dlp playlist re-stream FFMPEG constantly dropping

Tags: ffmpeg, video, youtube-dl, rtmp, yt-dlp

```
yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL63F0C78739B09958" --exec "ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -crf 23 -preset fast  -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytv10"
```

During the live broadcast, the live broadcast stops at the video transitions. It starts again in the second video. What can I do to keep it going without stopping?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try the following command: `yt-dlp "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL63F0C78739B09958" --no-break-per-input --wait-for-video 1000000 --fragment-retries "infinite" --retry-sleep linear=1::2 -o - | ffmpeg -i pipe: -vcodec libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -crf 23 -preset fast -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/mytv10`. I don't know if it's going to solve your issue. It's not stopping but not resuming... Please let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: Processed the first video. But it didn't process other videos. That's why the live broadcast was cut off again.  **Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it**